# Trying to find splitting fields over Q of $x^{19} -1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, roots, splitting-field

I'm trying to find subfields L of C which are splitting fields over Q

For $x^{19}-1$

I've found the roots, but since you can't express them in exact form I don't see what to do next.

Comment: Consider the cyclotomic field $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{19})$, see [here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/cyclotomic.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the splitting field is unique, and it is the unique extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ containing the roots of the polynomial $x^{19}-1$.

Now, if you call
$$\omega = e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{19}} = \cos\frac{2}{19}\pi + i \sin \frac{2}{19}\pi$$
then $\omega^{19} = e^{2 \pi i} = 1$, i.e. $\omega$ is a root of $x^{19}-1$.

With the same argument you can prove that $\{ \omega , \omega^2 , \dots , \omega^{18}, \omega^{19}=1\}$ are all the distinct roots of your polynomial. So your splitting field is
$L= \mathbb{Q}(\omega , \omega^2 , \dots) = \mathbb{Q}(\omega )$.